# Naming displays in Fedora 25's settings

Tags: fedora, xorg, configuration, graphics, multi-monitor

I  have fedora 25 running with dual head, and I have named each screen/monitor/device in `xorg.conf`, yet in the display settings they show up as 'Unknown Display'.

Is there a way to force Fedora to use the `xorg.conf` names?  Or perhaps rename them in Fedora?